# onclick function doesnt work after you click it once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used html link tag which call to onclick function.
but after i click some link once, the others link doesn't work (can't call the function again).

Html:

```
<a href='#' id='4' onclick='ChangeTxt(this.id);'>1</a>
<a href='#' id='11' onclick='ChangeTxt(this.id);'>2</a>
<a href='#' id='13' onclick='ChangeTxt(this.id);'>3</a>
```

JS:

```
<script>
function ChangeTxt(ClickID) {
    document.cookie="ClickID="+ClickID;
    <?php
        $newmessage="Smthing;
    ?>
  document.getElementById("Moditxt").innerHTML = <?php echo "\"".$newmessage."\""; ?>;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I wonder how does the first click even works

Comment: Assuming the missing quote is just a typo in the post only, is the script tag within `#Moditxt`?

Comment: As the name says `Miditxt`, I assume it is textbox then you need to use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: The value of `$newmessage` is never changed, maybe onclick is working, but it'll always put the same value to the element?

Comment: There may also be some confusion as to when server-side scripts run vis a vis a client-side event. @user3779174, PHP does not run when you click the elements; php runs when the page is requested and the resulting HTML is sent back to the browser. **If you want to run some PHP in response to a click event take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.**

Comment: the value $newmessage change in the real code, i just put an example... the problem is not with the php, because i use it in a different link with different value and it works

Comment: It doesn't change for sure, not as long as it is defined in PHP. Please read PeterKA's comment again. Your code in the page source looks like the value for `innerHTML`  was hardcoded to the file. Just hit F12 in your browser, and select "HTML" tab, and you'll see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

> $newmessage="Smthing;

- you probably have not entered the closing (");

Comment: This is example, it not the real code :-).... and i change it, it still not working

Comment: You have id='4', id='11', but the JavaScript says: document.getElementById("Moditxt"). Perhaps you could change the ID to "Moditxt"?

Answer (score 0):

.getElementById() only accesses the first element with the specified id. That could have something to do with it. I can't say for sure because I can't see the rest of your code.